# Where and in what format are custom dictionary files for common applications kept?

Tags: file-format, dictionary

I'm moving from my desktop workstation to a laptop, and have a great many custom technical, geographical and name entries in user dictionaries that I would be loathe to have to rebuild again from scratch.

Where can I find the various custom dictionaries on common programs such as Google Chrome, Lotus Notes, Microsoft Office, et cetra?

Comment: You had your answer in the question! It was one vote away from closure, so I put the final nail in it, edited the answer out, and voted to reopen.

Comment: This is, however, a list question. So it might not be a good candidate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112327/exceptional-cases-for-list-questions